# How I can get more decimal digits of p-value of chi-square in two-way table

Tags: stata, chi-squared

I use command `cchi2` to display each cell’s contribution to Pearson’s chi-squared in a two-way table in Stata. The p-value of each cell is displayed as 1 decimal, e.g., that the p-value is 0.0, but I would like to see more digits, e.g. 0.052 or .050.

Is there any possible way to set the digits of the p-value decimal?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This lacks a good reproducible example with a data call we can understand and in fact gives no code whatsoever. It also seems confused in terms of both Stata and statistics.

There is an option `cchi2` to the `tabulate` command when used with two variables. `cchi2` is **not** a separate command; it yields the contribution to chi-square and makes most sense when combined with the `chi2` option, e.g.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tab foreign rep78, chi2 cchi2

+-------------------+
| Key               |
|-------------------|
|     frequency     |
| chi2 contribution |
+-------------------+

           |                   Repair Record 1978
  Car type |         1          2          3          4          5 |     Total
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
  Domestic |         2          8         27          9          2 |        48 
           |       0.3        1.1        1.8        1.0        4.2 |       8.3 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
   Foreign |         0          0          3          9          9 |        21 
           |       0.6        2.4        4.1        2.3        9.5 |      19.0 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         2          8         30         18         11 |        69 
           |       0.9        3.5        5.9        3.3       13.7 |      27.3 

          Pearson chi2(4) =  27.2640   Pr = 0.000
```

Here we can see the contribution to chi-square; in this case 9.5 of the 27.264 chi-square statistic comes from the bottom right cell. These are not individual P-values; there is just one P-value, for the entire table, here given as 0.000 to 3 d.p.

One way of getting more detail is with the `tabchi` command downloadable with `ssc install tab_chi`. Here the `pearson` option gives the more useful Pearson residuals, (observed - expected) / square root of expected, which are the signed square roots of the contribution to chi-square.

```
. tabchi foreign rep78, pearson

          observed frequency
          expected frequency
          Pearson residual

--------------------------------------------------
          |           Repair Record 1978          
 Car type |      1       2       3       4       5
----------+---------------------------------------
 Domestic |      2       8      27       9       2
          |  1.391   5.565  20.870  12.522   7.652
          |  0.516   1.032   1.342  -0.995  -2.043
          | 
  Foreign |      0       0       3       9       9
          |  0.609   2.435   9.130   5.478   3.348
          | -0.780  -1.560  -2.029   1.505   3.089
--------------------------------------------------

4 cells with expected frequency < 5
1 cell with expected frequency < 1

          Pearson chi2(4) =  27.2640   Pr = 0.000
 likelihood-ratio chi2(4) =  29.9121   Pr = 0.000
```

Typing `return list` after that command gives more decimal places for the P-value:

```
. ret li

scalars:
                  r(N) =  69
                  r(r) =  2
                  r(c) =  5
               r(chi2) =  27.26396103896104
                  r(p) =  .0000175796084266
```

In your case, we can use your displayed frequencies to get Pearson residuals from the command `tabchii` in the same package.

```
. tabchii 3 10 2 \ 11 54 10, pearson

          observed frequency
          expected frequency
          Pearson residual

----------------------------------
          |          col          
      row |      1       2       3
----------+-----------------------
        1 |      3      10       2
          |  2.333  10.667   2.000
          |  0.436  -0.204   0.000
          | 
        2 |     11      54      10
          | 11.667  53.333  10.000
          | -0.195   0.091   0.000
----------------------------------

2 cells with expected frequency < 5

         Pearson chi2(2) =   0.2786   Pr = 0.870
likelihood-ratio chi2(2) =   0.2643   Pr = 0.876
```

In your case as the total chi-squared statistic happens to be less than 1, then all the contributions, the squares of (observed - expected) / expected, are also all less than 1, but (a) that is not true in general (b) they are not P-values (there isn't a separate test being carried out in each cell).

Both `tabchi` and `tabchii` do also have `cont` options equivalent to the `cchi2` option of `tabulate`. You can also tune the number of decimal places shown using `tabdisp` options, as documented.

Answer (score -1):

I think the quickest way to show the p value to more than 3 dp is to display stored results after you do your chi square:

```
. tab var1 var2, col chi

. display `r(p)'
```

Comment: The original version of this answer was gratuitously offensive; that's been edited out by others. There can be merit in short focused answers, but criticising other answers that are correct is not a good way to start contributing to SO.

Comment: This is correct in what it says but misses the point of the question "The p-value of each cell is displayed as 1 decimal". That is incorrect; what is also displayed in each cell is not a P-value, but as said a contribution to chi-square. As it happens, with `tabulate` the P-value is already displayed to 3 d.p. -- at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score -2):

There is an easy way to do it without using any software other than your browser.
This online statistical calculator can provide p value for up to 12 decimal points: https://www.icalcu.com/stat/chisqtest.html

For the first question, just paste the numbers below:

```
3 10 2
11 54 10
```

and you will get a p value of 0.869979427395

For the second dataset, just paste the numbers below:

```
2       8      27       9       2
0       0       3       9       9
```

and you will get a p value of 0.000017579608.

[image: Chi-square test calculator examples]

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it's answering the title of the question and not the confused question itself, which is about display of contributions to the chi-square statistic. Also, the question is about Stata, so answers in terms of other software are not expected.